# Invalid file path после добавления SVG файла в проект

Tags: android, xml, svg

Всем привет.
У меня есть svg файл, который я добавляю, как существующий, в проект. Ниже его код:

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg width="21pt" height="21pt" viewBox="0 0 21 21" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="#797979ff">
    <path fill="#797979" opacity="1.00" d=" M 20.48 0.00 L 21.00 0.00 L 21.00 20.48 C 20.87 20.61 20.62 20.87 20.49 21.00 L 0.00 21.00 L 0.00 20.38 C 6.82 13.64 14.25 7.00 20.48 0.00 Z" />
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Проект не компилируется из-за ошибки Invalid file path '(путь к файлу)'. Что я делаю не так?

> Нашел, что android проекты не поддерживают svg. Якобы файлы нужно в
> xml переделать.

Comment: Файл как называется? Подсказка же дана, что путь неверный. Наверное пробелы, большие буквы и т.д.

Comment: Нашел, что android проекты не поддерживают svg. Якобы файлы нужно в xml переделать. Протестирую и напишу по результату

Comment: @Frehzy Добавьте в вопрос скрин ошибки

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, svg надо сконвертировать в vector xml. В AndroidStudio есть для этого пункт меню file->new->vector asset:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="21dp"
    android:height="21dp"
    android:viewportWidth="21"
    android:viewportHeight="21">
  <path
      android:pathData="M20.48,0L21,0L21,20.48C20.87,20.61 20.62,20.87 20.49,21L0,21L0,20.38C6.82,13.64 14.25,7 20.48,0Z"
      android:fillColor="#797979"/>
</vector>
```

Во-вторых, не надо создавать никакие папки где попало. В ресурсах все папки имеют свой смысл и назначение. drawable ресурсы кладутся в res/drawable. Именно туда надо поместить сконвертированный из svg в xml файл (он сам туда сложится если пользоваться утилитой см выше).

NB не все svg будут корректно сконвертированы в vector, кроме того объем векторов также важен. Вектора предназначены в основном для иконок на кнопках. Если у вас какое-то большое изображение будет, делайте его в png, 9-patch.png...

Comment: Я делаю это в Visual Studio и у меня нет такой функции. Нашёл сайт - https://inloop.github.io/svg2android/, который позволяет из svg в vectorXml конвертировать, но куда его вставить, чтоб работало - вопрос. Когда вставляю в drawable, ничего не получается. Файл виден, но при попытке загрузить xml, на которой используется этот svg, выдаёт ошибку: Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'Drawable ru.program.android:drawable/testLoadSVG with resource ID #0x7f070057'. SVG файл имеет название "test.xml". Файл, в который загружаю - "testLoadSVG.xml"

Comment: @Yura Ivanov android не моя специализация. Только собираюсь этим заняться. Поэтому чисто спортивный интерес: AndroidStudio примет SVG для конвертации в xml со старыми написаниями namespace, как было в вопросе? (+)

Comment: По вашей ссылке написано, что надо пользоваться официальным тулом в андроид студии. Если вы собираетесь заниматься android'ом, то лучше сразу студию поставить. По visual studio вы полезных советов будете долго ждать. 
Содержимое сконвертированного файла я вложил в ответ. Сохраните его как test.xml, положите в папку res/drawable. Имена файлов в ресурсах должны быть в нижнем регистре и без пробелов, они являются идентификаторами, отсюда соответствующие требования к именованиям.
Конвертировал ваш исходный файл из вопроса, поэтому да, примет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать устаревшую форму записи - **namespace svg**

```
 <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"
```

Современная запись [namespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Если помню правильно, то запись:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`
Применялась раньше для **standalong** (автономных) svg файлов. Тоже лучше убрать, если файл используется в проекте

Итого:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="21pt" height="21pt" viewBox="0 0 21 21" version="1.1" >
    <g id="#797979ff">
       <path fill="#797979" opacity="1.00" d=" M 20.48 0.00 L 21.00 0.00 L 21.00 20.48 C 20.87 20.61 20.62 20.87 20.49 21.00 L 0.00 21.00 L 0.00 20.38 C 6.82 13.64 14.25 7.00 20.48 0.00 Z" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ошибка так и осталась: invalid file path 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Android\Program.Android\obj\Debug\120\res\svg\test.svg'. Program.Android

Comment: Попробовал ещё в сконвертировать в xml с помощью сайта https://products.aspose.app/pdf/ru/conversion/svg-to-xml, но ошибка не исчезает

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/G1ANV - вот такие свойства у этого файла. Оставил AndroidResourse, т.к. мне нужно будет его ещё в xml использовать

Comment: @Frehzy вы конвертировали свой файл или который я предложил в ответе?

Comment: Ваш. Может проблема связана с тем, что нужно как-нибудь для новосозданной папки svg, которую я создал в ресурсах, как-то путь прописать?

Comment: @Frehzy Да, наверняка, что-то надо изменить в настройках проекта

Comment: Сейчас покопаюсь и напишу, если что-нибудь найду

Comment: @Frehzy проверьте вновь созданную папку на права чтения и выполнения

Comment: Окей, оно сбилдилось, но теперь ошибка появляется при использовании этой xml. Раньше я использовал png вот так: https://pastenow.ru/G1B8I. Сейчас появляется ошибка. Я так понимаю, нужно тут переписать как-то, чтоб отображать svg Ошибка: Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'Drawable ru.program.android:drawable/testLoadSVG with resource ID #0x7f070057'